# Unable to run "npm install express redis socket.io --save" command on centos 7

Tags: php, node.js, sockets

I am working on a project where i have to display information to the client whenever any record inserted into the database.The project is developing using Laravel 5 framework based on PHP. For this purpose our team decide to use socket.io and i am the one who is working on the same.

**Efforts**

Till now i have istall redis, nodejs, php and the stuff required, but when i am running this command "npm install express redis socket.io --save" i don't understand whether it runs or not and how to test it.

I am getting this meesage on my terminal window:

```
[root@localhost ~]# npm install express redis socket.io --save
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
/root
├── express@4.14.0 
├── redis@2.6.3 
└── socket.io@1.5.1 

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/package.json'
npm WARN root No description
npm WARN root No repository field.
npm WARN root No README data
npm WARN root No license field.
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I am not able to unsderstand what is the issue behind, is i am missing somthing?

Please friends help me i am in very serious situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have package.json in root folder.

Please move to the correct folder or run `npm init` for making package.json

Comment: could you please elaborate, as i am very new to this. I am going to install nodejs, socket.io, redis wih laravel 5

Comment: Do you know where you need place your node.js application in the project?

Comment: I have simply install nodejs as i have run the above command. It may me in root.

Comment: Did you try to run `npm init` in the root folder?You should see questions. Press Enter or write answer for all of them. It will generate package.json for you.

Comment: I have, but i am confused to answer the question for the questions. Like i want to install express, redis, socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is due to the `--save` flag you added to the command.  If you are not creating a npm package, remove the `--save` from the command.  It would have added the three npm packages to the dependencies node in your package.json file.  Since you never initialized a npm package, you don't have the package.json file.  And if you are not creating a npm package for your project, you don't need the file.